# The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.13' was not found

Tags: c#, .net-core, centos, .net-standard

at the terminal of CentOS 8, I try to run the following:

```
dotnet -h
```

Error message:

```
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.13' was not found.
```

I have no idea of what is happening.

[image]

I have tried lots of instructions around the Google. Some of the steps that I have tried is as follow:

[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection\](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection%5C)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-centos

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
sudo dnf install aspnetcore-runtime-5.0
sudo dnf install dotnet-runtime-5.0
```

I also tried Enable snaps on CentOS and install .NET Runtime 5.0

https://snapcraft.io/install/dotnet-runtime-50/centos

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install snapd
sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
sudo snap install dotnet-runtime-50
```

but none of this resolve the problem.

---

## Update: Jan 26th 2022

Enter the following command:

```
dotnet --info
```

will get the following message:

[image: dotnet --info]

Then, I follow this steps explained at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup

by uninstalling and reinstalling the dotnet

```
sudo dnf remove packages-microsoft-prod
sudo dnf remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

then, I try the following:

```
dotnet --info
```

the system says something like (forget to screenshot):

```
dotnet cannot be found at
/user/var/bin/.... dotnet...
(I forget the exact path)
```

This is taking too much time to fix... that I have a more important task to do. I end up giving up to do further debugging this error. I deleted the CentOS and reinstall a brand new clean CentOS and start all over again. I believe I must have messed up multiple conflicting dotnet version and multiple error caching.

I will post another update once I have completed reinstalling new CentOS.

---

## Update 2: Jan 26th 2022 (Fixed)

Ok guys, the problem is fixed. By combining all the tips that you have provided, here is what I have done:

First, do a new clean installation of CentOS 8

Proceed to install the "dotnet"

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Test by running a console app:

```
dotnet ConsoleApp2.dll
```

Everything works perfectly fine now. Thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: There are two type libraries 1) The one used to compile 2) the one used to run.  You need to install the runtime on the linux machine.  See : https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0?force_isolation=true

Comment: After installing so much, what is the output of `dotnet --info`? Edit your question to include that please.

Comment: Could this be a case of https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup ?

Comment: @omajid Thanks for the tip. I have done that step, and updated the question above.

Comment: @LexLi ok, I have updated the question. After following omajid's suggested steps, then `dotnet --info` >> the system cannot find "dotnet" at something like... "/user/var/bin/....." I forget to screenshot this...

Comment: Okay guys... I'm don't want to mess around the settings... as I just need to test a short task. To save time, I deleted the CentOS and restart by reinstalling a brand new clean CentOS and start all over again.

Comment: Hi guys, the problem is fixed. I have updated in my question. Here is the summary of what I have done: Do a clean installation, reinstall the dotnet. and done. Thank you very much for the time and tips provided. I have combined the info provided by you guys and do an analysis and finally fixed. thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple source of dotnet runtime and sdk had been installed. This resulting multiple conflicting binary path and assembly caching crash.

Step 1: Do a clean installation of  CentOS

Step 2: Install required runtime version, for example:

```
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-3.1
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Step 3: Test by running a console app:

```
dotnet ConsoleApp.dll
```

done.

---

**Update: Alternative 2: Run the app without CentOS installing any runtime**

Another alternative option is to publish the .NET Core Project as "self-contained" into single binary.

[image]

Here is the example of how it looks like after publishing, there is only 1 single file:

[image]

Copy the compiled binary to CentOS

At the terminal, browse to the folder that contains the self-contained binary, for example:

```
cd /home/admin/testapp
```

Next, is to allow execution permission to the file:

```
sudo chmod 777 ConsoleApp2
```

Execute the app:

```
./ConsoleApp2
```